# Accidentally created duplicate objects? [Java]

Tags: java, object, duplicates

I want to create a class for playing cards, then put them in an ArrayList to serve as your hand during a game. Unfortunately, every time I try to draw a hand, every single playing card appears exactly the same when printed with a normal toString method, despite their suits and values being random. Here's the important pieces of code, and here's [the pastebin of the whole class file](http://pastebin.com/zYH2b4Zn/) (only 60 lines). Can anyone tell me what's going on here? My apologies if this is a duplicate question, I searched thoroughly.

```
private static char value;
private static String suit;

private static char [] values = {'A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', 'J', 'Q', 'K'};
private static String [] suits = {"Hearts", "Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds"};

public Card(){
    this.value = values[(int)(Math.random()*values.length)];
    this.suit = suits[(int)(Math.random()*suits.length)];
}

ArrayList<Card> hand = new ArrayList<Card>();

Card a = new Card();
Card b = new Card();
hand.add(a);
hand.add(b);

for (int i=0; i<hand.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(hand.get(i));
}
```

Comment: maybe show us what the actual output looks like? also, your `toString` is kinda important, too. and the way you implemented it, the `getValue` method as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that all your variables in `Card` class are **`static`**. The `static` modifier means that the variable/method will be a **class variable/method**. In other words, they exist only once per class, not per instance.

When you create the first `Card` instance, you are setting `value` and `suit` to some values. Then, when you create the second instance, those values are overwritten, because they only exist once per class.

**What can you do?** You can delete the `static` modifier from the variables and methods.

Comment: Thanks! Seemed to have worked. I do not understand the static modifier at all, it seems.